# Selecting data from multiple rows into a single row multiple columns

Tags: mysql-5.5, mariadb

I have a table that has columns like following. Batch number is a database design thing like row number

```
dm_id        type_in_id    type_student_id     amount
 36              1               1               1
 36              1               2               2
 36              1               3               3
 36              2               1               4
 36              2               2               5
 36              2               3               6
 36              3               1               7
 36              3               2               8
 36              3               3               9
```

I want to create a query that would return this:

```
dm_id  amount1 amount2 amount3 amount4 amount5 amount6 amount7 amount8 amount9
 36       1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9
```

How can I do that?

P.S. Version 5.5.56-MariaDB - MariaDB Server

Comment: Please tag your RDBMS, version included.

Comment: It is referred to as "pivot". Its realization is strongly DBMS-dependent - so specify it, including version.

Comment: Version 5.5.56-MariaDB - MariaDB Server

Comment: Stored procedure with dynamic SQL only... or (if dm_id-amount pairs are unique and amount values list is fixed) "pivot via grouping and aggregate".

Comment: Attempt to handle the data in its current form in your application rather than trying to get mariadb to transform this.

Comment: `type_in_id` and `type_student_id` fields values are ignored? `amount` values are used as both column headers and pivot values? strange...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT dm_ID, MAX(Amount1) Amount1, MAX(Amount2) Amount2,...
FROM (
SELECT dm_id,
CASE Value WHEN 1 THEN Value ELSE NULL END AS Amount1,
CASE Value WHEN 2 THEN Value ELSE NULL END AS Amount2,
....
FROM Table
) RearrangedData
```

Old school pivot. It will work, but you need to know the possible values of Amount column, to use in the CASE statement...  TSQL so should be supported by mySQL.